# Why does the general normal distribution include $\mu$ and $\sigma$?

Tags: statistics

The normal distribution function is defined as $$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$ 
I follow the logic of how and why we can obtain 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$$
and why this function is useful. So it should only be a small step from this to the general normal distribution. However, I don't understand the purpose of including $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in the exponent.

**My Question**

What purpose does including $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in the exponent serve? How does putting these variables in the exponent help with this?

**Remark:**

Also, $\sigma$ is a function of $\mu$
$$\sigma(\mu) = \sqrt{E[(x-\mu)^2]}$$ 
So isn't the normal distribution really only a function of $\mu$?

**Remark:**

All I really understand about $\sigma$'s role is that it affects the width of the distribution and $\mu$ affects where the distribution is centered.

Comment: $\sigma$ is not a function of $\mu$, they can be specified independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The density $$f(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2}, \quad -\infty < z < \infty,$$ corresponds to a random variable $Z$ that is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$.  This much should be clear.  Now we generalize this distribution by considering the location-scale family of such distributions characterized by $$X = \sigma Z + \mu,$$ i.e., we scale the random variable $Z$ by a factor of $\sigma > 0$, and add a location parameter $\mu$.  By the linearity of expectation, we see that $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \operatorname{E}[\sigma Z + \mu] = \operatorname{E}[\sigma Z] + \operatorname{E}[\mu] = \sigma \operatorname{E}[Z] + \mu = \sigma(0) + \mu = \mu,$$ and clearly $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{Var}[\sigma Z] = \sigma^2 \operatorname{Var}[Z] = \sigma^2 \cdot 1 = \sigma^2.$$  Consequently, $X$ has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.  The density of $X$ is found by observing that $$F_X(x) = \Pr[X \le x] = \Pr[\sigma Z + \mu \le x] = \Pr\left[Z \le \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}\right] = F_Z\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right),$$ consequently $$f_X(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left[F_Z\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right] = f_Z\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{\sigma}, $$ by the chain rule.  But this is precisely $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\mu$ and $\sigma$ are both independent defined by the distribution, so you have to input then on the distribution.
When you say $\sigma(\mu) = \sqrt{E[(X-\mu)^2]}$, you have to remember, also, that $\mu = E[X]$. Thus, in the end, both are defined by X.